# How to update cart item without refresh vuejs

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Every time I click the add the button and I need refresh the page to get the correct cart item count is there any way to update cart when clicked add button ?

tried onMounted need refresh to load the correct cart item count.

currentcart = localStorage

```
onMounted(async()=>{
  
  if(currentCart != null){
    await getCurrentCartLength();
  }
  
  console.log('Mounted');
})

const getCurrentCartLength = async()=>{
  (currentCart).forEach(async(value:{  prId: number; prQty: number; prSet:string }, index:number )=>{
    count.value = index+1 ;
  });
},
```

Comment: Do you send api request?

Comment: @Amini no the cart item is storing inside localstorage

Comment: After storing it in loaclStorage, get the items from localeStorage.

Comment: @Amini but there are two different components the cart display one component, another component is add item

Comment: You can use event emitters.

Comment: @Amini i tried to use $emit also, but the parent component cannot receive... you can check my post at here https://forum.vuejs.org/t/parent-component-data-doesnt-receive-using-this-emit/133969